# how to create Google Analytics SDK v4 for Android ecommerce_tracker.xml For tracker

Tags: android, xml, google-analytics

I don't have any sample code for google Analytics  even after installing google_paly_services library.
After following this link

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

i have been stuck in ecommerce_tracker.xml and PROPERTY_ID . I am not getting how to define it.

Answer (score 8):

PROPERTY_ID in your application class is "tracking id" value which you get when you create a google analytics account/ entry for your app.

And there is a sample xml configuration file for the "ecommerce_tracker.xml" in \extras\google\google_play_services\samples\analytics\res\xml where you have to enter ga_tracking id same as you get from above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Seriously don't understand why this info about the ecommerce_tracker.xml isn't documented anywhere. Would've saved alot of time. Thanks very much for your help!